# how to use mpiexec in linux shell

Tags: shell, pipe, mpiexec

I have a file a.txt and each line contains a parameter. Now I want to use mpiexec to call my program such as a.out to calculate with each parameter. So I use linux shell script to handle this. The code is sample

```
    cat a.txt | while read line
    do
        mpiexec -v -hostfile hosts -np 16 ./a.out ${line} 
    done
```

Unexpectedly, the script end after processing only one line of file a.txt. So, it is because of the wrong use of pipe? How can I tackle with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for LINE in `cat a.txt | xargs -r`; do
    mpiexec -v -hostfile hosts -np 16 ./a.out $LINE 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Claudio's solution helped set me on the right path to understanding why the loop exits after the first iteration. First off, here is a solution which is pretty close to what you wrote:

```
cat a.txt | while read line; do
    </dev/null mpiexec -np 16 ./a.out ${line}
done
```

Note that I am just using `mpiexec` on a local computer, (python's threading situation is bad enough to need this) so I can't test if this works with separate hosts. You can try adding that back in yourself.

The reason that your script didn't work is that `mpiexec` seems to gobble up whatever is attached to the standard input. I assume it does this so that in case `a.out` needs that input, it would gobble all the input and send it along with the command to run `a.out` that gets sent to the other servers. The result is that on the first iteration, `read` reads the first line from your file. Then `mpiexec` reads the rest of the lines, even though `a.out` probably doesn't use them in your case. Then on the second iteration, `read` tries to read more lines, but since `mpiexec` already read the rest, `read` is told that the end of file has been reached, so the loop exits.

Since we want to prevent `mpiexec` from reading the standard in, we redirect `mpiexec`'s standard in to come from /dev/null. Since /dev/null always contains nothing, `mpiexec` will read nothing and leave the standard input alone.

Comment: Some additional shell stuff to watch out for: if the file contains tabs or two spaces next to each other, then in order to make `line` preseve the tabs and spaces, `while read line` should become `while IFS= read line`. Also, if the file contains lines with any whitespace, and you want the entire line passed as an argument, then `${line}` should become `"$line"`. The way things are, line will get split into separate arguments if line contains whitespace. Which may be what you want, I don't know your use case.